# HLS streaming and bandwidth efficiency

Tags: streaming, cdn, http-live-streaming, adaptive-bitrate

I am observing when playing a HLS playlist that the player will go ahead and download the entire content as soon as it can rather then get segments just in time or perhaps only 2 or 3 ahead.

This is a problem because it is inefficient in terms of the volume of data pulled from the CDN.  If a user plays only 10% of a piece of content but downloads 100% of the data CDN costs will be much higher than they might be if the player only loaded a modest amount of data ahead of time.

What techniques are available to introduce a more conservative approach to data download? I'm more interested in mobile but the question applies equality to web.

Comment: You should have a way to set a maximum buffer size. Which player?

Comment: We are using the cordova media plugin https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/